# Implementing star DB structure using EF Code-First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I noticed that yet no one implemented start DB structure using Code-First.

Here is an example:

We have model `Log (Id, Message)`
and we have model `A1 (Id, Name, ICollection<Log> Logs)`

When you have only A1 then EF Migration script will create A1_Id in Log table

Problem happens when we have a lot of Models with `ICollection<Log> Logs`
because each model will add own "_Id" column to Log Table.

Is there a way to implement
this structure/tables

```
A1 (Id, Name, ... ,  ICollection<Log> Logs)
A2 (Id, Name, ... ,  ICollection<Log> Logs)
....
A102 (Id, Name, ... ,  ICollection<Log> Logs)

Log (Id, Message, OwnerId)
```

and so every time we need Logs for record in A77

EF will do this (select * from Log where OwnerId = 'id of record from A77')

I also don't want to create 102 foreign key constrains.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I guess it has to be somehow done in `protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method.

Comment: Do you really need to see the log very often? I would remove any referential constraint related to the log table, make it a stand alone table. Please refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794417/audit-tables-maintaining-referential-integrity-good-or-bad) as reference.

Comment: Yeah, and do you really want a separate TABLE for each log collection? There has to be a saner way than that...