# Cascading Deletes in SQL Sever 2008 not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I have the following table setup.

```
Bag
  |
  +-> BagID (Guid)
  +-> BagNumber (Int)

BagCommentRelation
  |
  +-> BagID (Int)
  +-> CommentID (Guid)

BagComment
  |
  +-> CommentID (Guid)
  +-> Text (varchar(200))
```

BagCommentRelation has Foreign Keys to Bag and BagComment.

So, I turned on cascading deletes for both those Foreign Keys, but when I delete a bag, it does not delete the Comment row.

Do need to break out a trigger for this?  Or am I missing something?

(I am using SQL Server 2008)

---

Note:  Posting requested SQL.  This is the defintion of the BagCommentRelation table.  (I had the type of the bagID wrong (I thought it was a guid but it is an int).)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bag_CommentRelation](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BagId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Sequence] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CommentId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bag_CommentRelation] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BagId] ASC,
    [Sequence] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bag_CommentRelation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bag_CommentRelation_Bag] FOREIGN KEY([BagId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Bag] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bag_CommentRelation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bag_CommentRelation_Bag]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bag_CommentRelation]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Bag_CommentRelation_Comment] FOREIGN KEY([CommentId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Comment] ([CommentId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Bag_CommentRelation] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Bag_CommentRelation_Comment]
GO
```

The row in this table deletes but the row in the comment table does not.

Answer (score 1):

With your current structrue, the `BagComment` record wouldn't be deleted when you delete a `Bag`, only the `BagCommentRelation` record.  The delete cascades from `Bag` to `BagCommentRelation`, but stops there.  The structure you have looks like a Many-to-Many relationship between `Bag` and `BagCommentRelation`.  Why do you need `BagCommentRelation`?

Edit: It sounds like the easiest thing to do would be to make your structure like this:

```
Bag 
  | 
  +-> BagID (Guid)
  +-> BagNumber (Int)

BagComment 
  | 
  +-> BagID (Guid)
  +-> Text (varchar(200))
```

but using the `BagComment` (or `Comment`) table to refer to multiple objects add some complexity.  If that's what you need to do, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294969/sql-one-foreign-key-references-primary-key-in-one-of-several-tables) should provide assistance.

Comment: Our comment table has lots of different types of comments.  Some tables uses Guids, some ints for the PK.  Also, one bag may have many comments.

Sounds like I need to pick either guids or ints and have the FK go directly from my bag table.

Answer (score 1):

Your table BagCommentRelation in as n:m relation between Bag and BagComments, so it is a detail table to both other tables.

A DELETE CASCADE constraint will only work towards the detail table, so clearly a BagComment cannot be deleted if a Bag is deleted.

Which makes me wonder how a bag comment can be applied to several bags.

If you *really* need to have the same BagComment used for different Bag records, I suggest a DELETE trigger on Bag_CommentRelation which deletes all BagComments that are no longer referenced by the relation table.

Comment: A comment can only be applied to one item (bag, user whatever).  We may have used the wrong table structure for this.  If we have a one to many (bag to comment) relation then do we just have a CommentID in the bag table and then a FK From bag to comment? (and ditch the Relation table?)

Comment: @Vaccano yes, you don't need the BagCommentRelation. Just adding a BagID to BagComment should be enough (if you need more than 1 comment for a Bag)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not use cascading delete at all. What if the need came to a large group of bags? Cascade delete could tie up your tables for hours. It is a better practice to specifically write the deletes you need.